# Postgres update multiple row in one action

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have two tables

```
app_detail_quot_s
-----------+--------------+
part_id    +unit_price    +
-----------+--------------+
1          +    100.000   +
2          +    200.000   +
3          +    300.000   +


app_supp_po_dt
-----------+--------------+
part_id    +unit_price    +
-----------+--------------+
1          +    null      +
2          +    null      +
8          +    null      +
```

the result after query update  executed is

```
app_supp_po_dt
-----------+--------------+
part_id    +unit_price    +
-----------+--------------+
1          +    100.000   +
2          +    200.000   +
8          +    null      +
```

how to UPDATE all `unit_price` when `part_id`  between `app_detail_quots` and `app_supp_po_detail` is equal in just one action using PostgreSQL?

I am trying this code:

```
update app_supp_po_dt set
    unit_price =
 ( 
    select unit_price from app_detail_quot_s a left join app_supp_po_dt b on    a.part_id= b.part_id
 )
```

But I get error :

> more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the join inside the sub-select, just make it a regular co-related sub-select:

```
update app_supp_po_dt 
 set unit_price = (select unit_price 
                   from app_detail_quot_s a 
                   where a.part_id = app_supp_po_dt.part_id);
```

The above assumes that `part_id` is unique in both tables.

The co-related sub-query will return `null` if a `part_id` is not found in `app_detail_quot_s` and will overwrite any value stored in `app_supp_po_dt` in that case, if you do not want that, you need to exclude rows from `app_supp_po_dt` that have a unit price but do not appear in `app_detail_quot_s`

```
update app_supp_po_dt 
 set unit_price = ( select unit_price from app_detail_quot_s a where a.part_id = app_supp_po_dt.part_id)
where unit_price is null
  and exists (select 1 
              from app_detail_quot_s a2 
              where a2.part_id = app_supp_po_dt.part_id);
```

Another (non-standard) option is to use a join in the `update` statement, which makes the statement a bit more readable:

```
update app_supp_po_dt 
  set unit_price = a.unit_price
from app_detail_quot_s a
where a.part_id = app_supp_po_dt.part_id;
```

This is non-standard SQL and will not work on other DBMS, but is most probably much faster than the solutions with a co-related sub-query

Comment: thank for your tips @a_horse_with_no_name, but I am sucees trying my own
query who relevant in my case  this is my newer query 
in my real case
update app_supp_po_dt set
    unit_price= 
 ( 
    select price from app_detail_quot_s a 
    left join app_supp_po_dt b on a.part_id= b.part_id
           left join app_quots c on a.quot_s_id= c.id
           left join app_supp_po d on c.id=d.quots_id
     where a.part_id=b.part_id
 ) 
thank U

Comment: @Alimin: do **not** post code in comments. **Edit** your question - but don't change the question completely. If you have a new question, then ask a new question

Comment: I just want helping someone  when they have some problem like me in future, in other time I use your advice ok, please approve my question  -_-